# dropdowns only trigger once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, zurb-foundation, turbolinks

I have two filter dropdowns on [this site](http://murmuring-mountain-9361.herokuapp.com/) which will only trigger the first time I press them. According to my studies it seems that it has to do with turbolinks, which I've disabled by adding data-no-turbolink to the body tag like so:

```
<body data-no-turbolink>
...
</body>
```

I've also tried adding this to all of the dropdown links and the link to open the dropdown.

```
<a href="some-link" data-no-turbolink>...</a>
```

It seems to work on development, but when I push to Heroku, it seems turbolinks are running again. Any suggestions?

Comment: How about removing Turbolinks entirely? As per e.g. [these instructions](http://blog.steveklabnik.com/posts/2013-06-25-removing-turbolinks-from-rails-4).

Comment: Tried that, but was not able to start the server, so other parts of my app was relying on turbolinks.

Comment: You weren't able to start the server?  Does that mean you don't know whether or not the suggested fix will work?

Comment: What kind of an error message does starting the server generate? Does this happen in development or on Heroku only?

Comment: I did not make a note of the error message, but tried again removing turbolinks as suggested in the guide above, to see if I could reproduce it and this time it worked. Problem solved! Thanks! If you post your comment as an answer I would be happy to approve it :)

Comment: @funkylaundry: Sure, I need to start racking up some points :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Turbolinks is an issue, it can be removed entirely from the project by following the instructions provided e.g. [here](http://blog.steveklabnik.com/posts/2013-06-25-removing-turbolinks-from-rails-4):

1. remove `gem 'turbolinks'` from the Gemfile and run `bundle update`
2. remove `//= require turbolinks` from **app/assets/javascripts/application.js**
3. remove `"data-turbolinks-track" => true` from the `stylesheet` and `javascript` tags in the header of **application.html.erb** layout file.

Quoting *Rails 4 In Action*:

> ...it's our opinion that Turoblinks is great to speed up
>   mostly-server-side sites, but as soon as you start writing some
>   JavaScript, it causes more problems than it's worth.