# Delete link behaviour lost when I regenerate HTML. How can I handle this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I regenerate a Rails delete link on my page, something like the following:

```
<a href="/categories/19" data-method="delete" data-confirm="Are you sure?" ..>Link</a>
```

When this page loads, something in Rails must set the behaviour of this link as I get a nice "Are you sure?" before I commit to delete something. However, when I regenerate the HTML I'm guessing I need to re-initialize the behaviour but I'm not sure where this comes from. Can anyone tell me if there is a function I should call again after I generate this HTML link? Thanks

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: When I regenerate the HTML links, the JavaScript link behaviour is lost. For example, when I have a delete link (with data-method="delete" and data-confirm="Are you sure?") it handles it by displaying a delete confirmation. This is lost when the new HTML is generated. I understand why this is happening, but I don't know how to fix it whereby I can re-apply the original link behaviour (show cofirmation box) as well as turbolinks main purpose of loading the pages in the current maintained state. I want the links to behave as they did before the re-generation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean that the "Are you sure?" pop-up message fails to work after you reload the page, the issue may lie with Turbolinks. Have a look at [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23606078/dropdowns-only-trigger-once/23656281#23656281) to see how to a). disable Turbolinks for individual links; b). disable it for the whole HTML document; or c). remove it from your Rails project entirely (probably without noticeable impact).

Comment: I see, it's in turbolinks. Actually I want to keep the behaviour. I'd like to reapply the link behaviour to the later generated HTML. Is there something I can call in turbolinks that would re-apply behaviour to the links? I don't need to worry about re-adding behaviour to a link as I completely replace all links in question.

Comment: When you say "keep the behaviour", do you mean keep the pop-up message working, or you are happy with it not working after a page reload? If the former, have a look [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#turbolinks). Unless you want to get immersed in JavaScript, your best course of action is probably to add `data-no-turbolink` to your `link_to`.

Comment: I want to keep turbolinks, but I want to re-bind the pop-up message click events to the newly generated links. I've had a look in the turbolinks.js file but it doesn't seem like there is any way to call the functions outwith the closure it's wrapped in. So it seems I can't use turbolinks delete link behaviour if I'm going to be generating links.

Comment: Actually the functionality seems to be nothing to do with turbolinks. I've disabled it and couldn't work out why the confirm was still appearing. The functionality lives in jquery_ujs file, it creates a $.rails object with a load of methods, but I can't figure from there how to re-assign the confirm message before delete.

Comment: Turbolinks has nothing to do with the confirm box appearing, that is handled by JavaScript. The problem is that Turbolinks prevents the JavaScript from firing after page reloads, which is why you don't see the confirm pop-up on subsequent clicks. Disabling Turbolinks for this link, for the page, or for the whole project will ensure that JavaScript (here, your confirm box) always functions properly. The purpose of Turbolinks is to speed up page loads as a user browses your site, but the performance gains are likely to be minor, while interference with JavaScript is a real nuisance.

Comment: I removed turbolinks entirely so my app doesn't use it anymore, at all, but the issue remains. So I came to the conclusion that TL isn't interfering at all, I need to re-assign the link behaviour after I regenerate HTML (using jQuery.html(...) ). I found mention of this functionality in jquery_ujs (go into this file, search for "delete"). I just can't find the function that takes the link(s) and assigns the onclick event. If I could find how it assigns the onclick event $.rails.*something* then I could re-assign the link behaviour to the links after I generate the HTML. No?

Comment: After jQuery swaps in the new HTML, do the links still contain `data-confirm='Are you sure?'` Does the new HTML include all the relevant `<script>` tags?

Comment: No, they contained `data-cofirm="Are you sure?"` .. mis-spelling!! *facepalm* Sorry! I've changed it to data-confirm and it works now. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your problem lies in the javascript you use to set up the link.  The sequence of events is something like this:

1. page loads
2. dom ready js runs and attaches onclick events to everything with a data-confirm attribute
3. some other js runs later and adds a new element with a data-confirm attribute.  This doesn't have the onclick, because it wasn't in the dom when step2 happened.

One solution to this is to make sure that the js which sets up the links is in a function which can be called when you add the new element to the page.  Then you can add a call to this to the js which adds the new element.

The gotcha with this is that you could end up re-adding the functionality to the elements that are already there, so that they now have two onclick events, each of which does the same thing (so it happens twice).  To cope with this your code could avoid adding it to elements which already have that event, OR strip the event off all elements which would get the onclick, THEN apply the onclick.

Alternatively, you could set up the code to take an argument which is an selector, and it only applies the onclick event to elements **within* the element with the selector.  So when you call it in dom ready you pass "body" and when you do it later you pass "#id-of-new-div-being-loaded" or something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, this will turn off turbolinks for this particular URL only

```
<span data-no-turbolink><a href="/categories/19" data-method="delete" data-confirm="Are you sure?" ..>Link</a></span>
```